# Unable to install Spring tool suite 4 on eclipse (Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0) Build id: 20200313-1211)

Tags: spring-tool-suite, eclipse-marketplace, spring-tools-4

i am trying to install STS4 using eclipse marketplace. however i encountered the following error.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: BOSH Language Server Feature 4.6.1.202004200519 (org.springframework.tooling.bosh.ls.feature.feature.group 4.6.1.202004200519)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse Language Server Commons 4.6.1.202004200519 (org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 4.6.1.202004200519) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.apache.commons.lang3 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: BOSH Manifest Language Server 1.17.0.202004200519 (org.springframework.tooling.bosh.ls 1.17.0.202004200519)
    To: osgi.bundle; org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons 4.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: BOSH Language Server Feature 4.6.1.202004200519 (org.springframework.tooling.bosh.ls.feature.feature.group 4.6.1.202004200519)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.springframework.tooling.bosh.ls [1.17.0.202004200519,1.17.0.202004200519]

i am unable to understand the issue.

additionally, eclipse am using is packaged. its not installed on the drive.

thanks.

Comment: This looks like the installation procedure can't find the `org.apache.commons.lang3` bundle, which is not part of the Spring Tools 4 update repository, but comes from your main Eclipse update site. This is usually preconfigured in your preferences (`Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites`). Can you double check?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, i checked in preferences path. its not available in the specified path.

Comment: please follow the GitHub wiki for manual installation then: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Installation - hope that helps!